# Transformation types in geo-referencing of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I am a beginner in geomatics.

I am trying to georeference some images in QGIS.

I would like to understand what is happening behind the different transformation types (linear, polynomial, Helmert...).
What I don't understand is the red lines that appear after inserting a GCP. These lines take as a starting point the point the user put, but I don't understand their orientation.

Does this show a gap between the coordinates given by the user and the coordinates of the map?

Example : 
http://hpics.li/dbe04f9

Answer (score 39):

The following are quoted from the QGIS docs regarding the [Available Transformation algorithms](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/georeferencer.html#available-transformation-algorithms):

- The **Linear** algorithm is used to create a world file and is different from the other algorithms, as it does not actually transform the raster. This algorithm likely won’t be sufficient if you are dealing with scanned material.
- The **Helmert** transformation performs simple scaling and rotation transformations.
- The **Polynomial** algorithms 1-3 are among the most widely used algorithms introduced to match source and destination ground control points. The most widely used polynomial algorithm is the second-order polynomial transformation, which allows some curvature. First-order polynomial transformation (affine) preserves collinearity and allows scaling, translation and rotation only.
- The **Thin Plate Spline** (TPS) algorithm is a more modern georeferencing method, which is able to introduce local deformations in the data. This algorithm is useful when very low quality originals are being georeferenced.
- The **Projective** transformation is a linear rotation and translation of coordinates.

In terms of the red lines , these are likely be [georeferencing errors](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/map_georeferencing.html#basic-fa-georeferencing-the-scanned-map) which can show the residual difference between various sets of map control points.