# Georeferenced image tilting

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, georeferencing

I need to Georeference a map which is given in .jpg format (Data source).

[image]

I reference the map using QGIS Georeferencer. The Georeference was successful and coordinate system was saved to WGS 84/UTM Zone 56s EPSG:32756.
However, the georeferenced map when add to QGIS window is tilted as shown in figure below:-
[image]

I tried to georeference the .jpg map with respect to coordinate of Google Earth Image (in EPSG:32756). The image point georeferenced with respect to Google Earth Image is as shown below:-
[image]

The transformation setting of georeferenced image (Transformation Type: Polynomial 2 & Resampling Method: cubic has been asked to apply compulsorily) with respect to Google Earth Image is as shown below:-

[image]

Which is the georeferenced image tilted? Is that because of lesser point chosen for georeferenced or other? Is that because of not defining source properties in Georeferencer as EPSG:32756.How can this problem be resolved?

Note: The above first image can be used as source image for solving this issue.

Comment: "after changing sentinel to WGS 84/UTM Zone 56s EPSG:32756". Re-project, don't "change".

Comment: @Pointdump I tried using Reproject layer from Processing toolbox & try to add the the sentinel image as Input layer in Parameter of Reproject layer. But, its showing Couldn't load source layer for sentinel data.

Comment: Try Export >> Save As.

Comment: @Pointdump; I tried using your suggestion but it's not working. The georeferenced map that should lie below sentinel-2 lies far beyond it as shown above.

Comment: I guess at this point you need to figure out what is right. Maybe compare both images to Google Satellite or Bing Live Maps.

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383437/88814

Comment: @Pointdump I now tried georeferencing image with respect to Google Earth Image as per your suggestion. But it's being tilted.

Comment: You should add more information - step by step a) what input you have (maybe sharing data) and b) the steps you undertook. Without that, it's difficult to say where something went wront. Almost certainly, it is one of the very common wrong CRS settings as described in the post I linked.

Comment: @Babel I have provided here with image data source as per your suggestions. Please review through questions and help me solving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What the problem was

Your image is quite easy to georeference as A) it has a grid on it with coordinate values and B) the CRS/projection used for it is known: the map was created in `WGS 1984 UTM zone 56S` (`EPSG:32756` as the text next to the map states). So use grid intersections for GCP (Ground Control Points). You probably had the wrong CRS definition assigned to your GCP when creating the points.

### Solution: how to solve the problem

See the next screenshot: I defined 6 GCP (6 is the minimum for Polynominal 2 transformation, as you have it - see below for more on transformation types). I used grid intersections to place the GCP's, than manually filled in the coordinate values I got from the grid's labels.

Be aware: in the `Enter Map Coordinates` dialog, be sure to have the CRS set to `EPSG:32756` (see screenshot). The grid is in that CRS, so if you assign another CRS to these coordinate values, georeferencing will be wrong.

[image]

After defining 6 GCP, I made the transformation settings as in your screenshot.

See the result:

[image]

### Choose simpler transformation settings

By the way: in this very easy case where you have a map already in a known CRS/projection and with a grid, you don't need the more complex polynominal 2 transformation. You can use `Linear` transformation type with a minimum of just two GCP - but make sure that in transformation settings, you have set Target CRS to `EPSG:32756`.

See here for the different transformation types:

- [GIS SE: Differences between different georeferencing transformation algorithms in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/370248/88814)
- [QGIS documentation: Available Transformation Algorithms](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/georeferencer.html#available-transformation-algorithms)
- [GIS SE: Transformation types in geo-referencing of QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/226948/88814)